# How to query AWS Stack Outputs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

My Stack Outputs:

```
            "Outputs": [
            {
                "OutputKey": "InstanceId",
                "OutputValue": "i-0ed2834d95ae5bb98",
                "Description": "Instance Id"
            },
            {
                "OutputKey": "PrivateIp",
                "OutputValue": "10.176.66.46",
                "Description": "Private IP address"
            },
            {
                "OutputKey": "EbsVolumeId",
                "OutputValue": "vol-03837489a20032881",
                "Description": "EbsVolume"
            }
```

I tried to query the PrivateIp of stack by using the command below but the command doesn't return anything.

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name my-stack-01 --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=="PrivateIp"].OutputValue" --output text
```

What did I do wrong?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You must use single-quotes in the filter part `?OutputKey=="PrivateIp"` of your query. So, change your whole query to:

`aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name my-stack-01 --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='PrivateIp'].OutputValue" --output text`

This will work.