# Gitlab CI/CD - re-use old variable in child pipeline without being triggered by parent pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

##### The use case

Two projects hosted on Gitlab: a simple single page application and an AWS stack for a serverless backend.
Having two distinct projects makes the permission handling more secure and flexible since we can have two distinct teams (frontend and devops) each one working independently on its own part of the whole project.

This bringes the needs to have the aws project pipeline to pass down the references to the aws resources (e.g. the S3 buckets where to deploy the spa static assets for staging and development or the gateway stages urls for api calls) to compile the spa static assets.

#### The problem

I know from the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#pass-cicd-variables-to-a-downstream-pipeline) that a parent pipeline can pass variables to child pipelines when executed, but in my use case its expected that the spa project pipeline will be triggered more often by direct commits than the parent pipeline, so I'm wondering how to provide the S3 reference in these cases.

Does this make sense or am I missing something and going in the wrong direction?

Comment: I understand you need to figure out a way how you can pass the s3 references when the CI/CD pipeline is triggered by a direct commit and not a parent pipeline, correct?

Comment: I think this might help you https://forum.gitlab.com/t/data-sharing-between-multi-project-pipelines/65692/2

Comment: Also, you can include an initial stage that has a rule to be triggered only if the pipeline was triggered by another one as a downstream. In this initial stage, you can retrieve all the states you want from a predefined storage of your selection. Maybe you can earlier store the states in a custom S3 location or in the CI/CD vars

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it.

I was going in the wrong direction: cloudformation templates have a dedicated [Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) section that is made exactly to output desired information about the stack.
As described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943162/how-to-query-aws-stack-outputs), those values can be retrieved with the [`describe-stacks`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) aws cli command, e.g.:

```bash
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name my-stack-01 --query <query>
```

So there's no need to have values being passed directly between pipelines, I just can retrieve them in a dedicated job in the child pipeline.